# A sequence of intervals- Trying to find a fixed point -

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, numerical-methods

This might be a trivial question but I couldn't come up with a clever trick,theorems or whatnot.

Suppose $I_0=\left[\frac{1}{h_0},\frac{1}{l_0}\right]$ where $h_0=1$ and $l_0=\frac{1}{2}$. Given $k_0\in\left[1,2\right]$  constant, define inductively
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{2k_0}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}\int_{I_{n-1}}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}F
$$
and
$$
I_{n}=\left[\frac{1}{h_n},\frac{1}{l_n}\right]\cap I_0
$$
where $h_n=2a_n+\frac{2-l_{n-1}}{3}$ and $l_n=2a_n+\frac{2-h_{n-1}}{3}$. I want to show that $lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=\{k_0\}$. I try to invoke Cantor intersection theorem, but I can't show $I_n\supset I_{n+1}$, though it is trivial for $n=0$. My other observation is $h_n-l_n=\frac{h_{n-1}-l_{n-1}}{3}$ and tried to use this in order to show that the length of $I_n$s decreasing. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is $F$ ($dF$ in the integral)?

Comment: It is a cdf function.

Comment: You can just slog it out. You have upper and lower bounds for the integral (interval width x $l_n$ and interval width x $h_n$). As you say, it is fairly easy to show the interval width goes to zero. The trickier part is showing that $I_n\subset I_{n-1}$. It looks fairly messy to me.